# how to prevent button to trigger a postback on aspx

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, popup

It has been a while since I last made a website with JQUERY-UI. I am have a aspx page, and I am trying to add a popup modal on click of

but it triggers a "submit" when I click the button, how do I prevent the submit? It displays the popup for 2 seconds and then "submit" occurs.

here is the html code

```
    <div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
      <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

      <form>
      <fieldset>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>


    <div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
      <h1>Existing Users:</h1>
      <table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
        <thead>
          <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Password</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>John Doe</td>
            <td>john.doe@example.com</td>
            <td>johndoe1</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <button id="create-user">Create new user</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prevent submit action -

```
$('form').on('submit',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In you Jquery code where you are setting the popup write 
return false in the end... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to return false OnClientClick, `<asp:Button OnClientClick="return false;"></button>`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the type attribute in the button, `type="button"`. By default it is `submit`